# Grouping the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Suppose, I have the data like this,

```
 Date      Time    Energy_produced
01.01.2016   00:00      500
01.01.2016   00:15      580
01.01.2016   00:30      600
01.01.2016   00:45      620
01.01.2016   01:00      580
01.01.2016   01:15      520
01.01.2016   01:30      590
01.01.2016   01:45      570
01.01.2016   02:00      540
```

Now, i want to sum the energy produced based on each hour

suppose ,

```
Date          Hour      Energy produced per hour
01.01.2016   00:00      2280(per hour)
01:01:2016   01:00      2240(per hour)
```

How to sum like this?

Comment: What is the dtype of your columns "Date" and "Time"? String?

Comment: Create additional column that extract the hour from `time` column, and then group by date and new column.

Comment: @Mr.T dtype is strings

Comment: @sagi May I know, how to extract hour from time column?

Comment: df['time'][:2] will give you the first two characters if this column is of string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep Date/Time as strings, you could use:

```
(df.groupby(['Date', df['Time'].str[:3].rename('Hour')+'00'])
   ['Energy_produced'].sum()
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
         Date   Hour  Energy_produced
0  01.01.2016  00:00             2300
1  01.01.2016  01:00             2260
2  01.01.2016  02:00              540
```

*NB. You can also get the second group with: `df['Time'].str.replace(r'\d{2}$', '00', regex=True).rename('Hour')`*